# zend redirect in different language

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

Using **Zend Framework**, I have an action called my_action and two languages, en and de, so the calls are like this:

- /en/my_action/my_english_parameteres
- /de/mein_handeln/mein_deutsch_parameter

How can I change the routes.ini so, whenever someone browses at:

- /de/mein_handeln/mein_deutsch_parameter

to automatically redirect at this:

- /en/my_action/my_english_parameteres

Can this be done in the routes.ini or using some preDispatch() action?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend_Translate and custom routes then router can translate routes for you.

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$routes['account'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  '/@myaccount/@settings',
  array(
    'module' => 'user',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'account',
  ));
$router->addRoutes($routes);
```

Using '@' before name in path causes router to search for translation. Now you can create links like this `$this->url(array(), 'account')` and it will translate it to correct language (if it will not find `myaccount`/`settings` then address will remain unchanged)